# Making an IObservable<T> that uses async/await return completed tasks in original order

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Suppose you have a list of 100 urls and you want to download them, parse the response and push the results through an IObservable:

```
public IObservable<ImageSource> GetImages(IEnumerable<string> urls)
{
    return urls
        .ToObservable()
        .Select(async url =>
        {
            var bytes = await this.DownloadImage(url);
            var image = await this.ParseImage(bytes);
            return image;
        });
}
```

I have some problems with this.

One is that it's bad etiquette to hammer a server with 100 requests at the same time -- ideally you would rate limit to maybe 6 requests at a given moment. However, if I add a `Buffer` call, due to the async lambda in `Select`, everything still fires at the same time.

Moreover, the results will come back in a different order than the input sequence of URLs, which is bad, because the images are part of an animation that will be displayed on the UI.

I've tried all kinds of things, and I have a solution that's working, but it feels convoluted:

```
public IObservable<ImageSource> GetImages(IEnumerable<string> urls)
{
    var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(6);

    return Observable.Create<ImageSource>(async observable =>
    {
        var tasks = urls
            .Select(async url =>
            {
                await semaphore.WaitAsync();
                var bytes = await this.DownloadImage(url);
                var image = await this.ParseImage(url);
            })
            .ToList();

        foreach (var task in tasks)
        {
            observable.OnNext(await task);
        }

        observable.OnCompleted();
    });
}
```

It works, but now I'm doing `Observable.Create` instead of just `IObservable.Select`, and I have to mess with the semaphore. Also, other animations that run on the UI stop when this is running (they're basically just `DispatcherTimer` instances), so I think I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: I think TPL Dataflow library might suit your requirements better than Rx here.

Comment: nah, I got this, don't worry :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
urls.ToObservable()
    .Select(url => Observable.FromAsync(async () => {
        var bytes = await this.DownloadImage(url);
        var image = await this.ParseImage(bytes);
        return image;        
    }))
    .Merge(6 /*at a time*/);
```

#### What are we doing here?

For each URL, we're creating a *Cold Observable* (i.e. one that won't do anything at all, until somebody calls Subscribe). `FromAsync` returns an Observable that, when you Subscribe to it, runs the async block you gave it. So, we're Selecting the URL into an object that will do the work for us, but only if we ask it later.

Then, our result is an `IObservable<IObservable<Image>>` - a stream of Future results. We want to flatten that stream, into just a stream of results, so we use `Merge(int)`. The merge operator will subscribe to `n` items at a time, and as they come back, we'll subscribe to more.  Even if url list is very large, the items that Merge are buffering are only a URL and a Func object (i.e. the description of *what* to do), so relatively small.

Comment: Thanks! I had found the `Merge` function somewhere, but I couldn't find the overload that takes one int, because it hadn't clicked with me that I should be using a Cold Observable. 

(Also saves me from having to return a Task<IObservable<T>>)

It turns out that the `ParseImage` function needs to run on on the UI thread, because on Windows Phone it uses the GPU. So I had to move that back to the subscriber. 

Another thing still missing is that the results are pushed in the order that the tasks complete in. I solved that by using the `Select(Func<T, int>) overload and sorting it out in the UI.

Comment: If you want results to be processed in-order (at the expense of speed), just replace `Merge(6)` above with `Concat()`

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve what you want is to use the `Observable.StartAsync` method, a [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim), and the `Concat` operator. The `Observable.StartAsync` will create hot observables (started immediately), the `SemaphoreSlim` will throttle the downloading/parsing of the images, and the `Concat` will collect the images in the original order.

```
public IObservable<ImageSource> GetImages(IEnumerable<string> urls, int maxConcurrency)
{
    return Observable.Using(() => new SemaphoreSlim(maxConcurrency), semaphore =>
        urls
            .ToObservable()
            .Select(url => Observable.StartAsync(async cancellationToken =>
            {
                await semaphore.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);
                try
                {
                    var bytes = await this.DownloadImage(url);
                    var image = await this.ParseImage(bytes);
                    return image;
                }
                finally { semaphore.Release(); }
            }))
            .Concat());
}
```

You could consider passing the `cancellationToken` argument to the `DownloadImage` and `ParseImage` methods, in order to avoid having fire-and-forget operations running in the background, in case that the resulting `IObservable<ImageSource>` terminates prematurely for any reason (error or unsubscription).

Comment: Caution, the `Concat` operator [behaves wierdly](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/issues/1634) in the current version of the Rx library (5.0.0). My advice is to use the equivalent `Merge(1)` operator instead, until the issue with the `Concat` is fixed. The `1` is the value of the `maxConcurrent` parameter. Setting this parameter to `1` means no concurrency.